# Mac Leopard - Can't start Apache2 after building SVN1.6.2 from source

Tags: svn, macos, apache2

Last Thursday I built SVN from source on my Mac running Leopard 10.5.7 so that I could get svn+ssh capability. (For some reason that functionality wasn't available using the binary from Collabnet.)

The build was successful and I was able to use SVN afterwords, but apache stopped launching.

When I tracked down the error, this is what I'm getting:

```
Syntax error on line 117 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec
/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so, 10): no
suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so: mach-o, but
wrong architecture
```

I suspect that doing the build mucked something up but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Apple built Apache as a fat binary so it supports four architectures so it will only load modules which are built as fat binaries. You can use the [`lipo`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) utility to figure out how something was built:

```
lorien$ lipo -info /usr/sbin/httpd
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/sbin/httpd are: ppc7400 ppc64 i386 x86_64
```

Chances are that you will see something like this:

```
lorien$ lipo -info /usr/libexec/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
Non-fat file: /usr/libexec/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so is architecture: i386
```

You can use [`arch`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/arch.1.html) to force a command to run in one mode or another or the `lipo` utility to modify the binary and strip out certain variants. Overall, it is quite a pain to deal with on a case by case basis.

The other option is to compile everything into fat binaries which is what I have been doing lately. With autoconf based things (just about anything with a `configure` script), you can usually control much of the process with environment variables. I have a bunch of scripts that wrap the build process to make sure that they get set up correctly. Use the following commands to rebuild svn:

```
lorien$ cd ~/src/svn-1.6.2
lorien$ cat env-sh
ARCHFLAGS="-arch ppc -arch ppc64 -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
DEVPATH='/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk'
CPPFLAGS="-isysroot $DEVPATH"
CFLAGS="$ARCHFLAGS $CPPFLAGS"
CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-syslibroot,$DEVPATH $ARCHFLAGS"
MACOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS MACOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
lorien$ . env-sh
lorien$ ./configure ... 
lorien$ make -j2
lorien$ lipo -info subversion/mod_dav_svn/.libs/mod_dav_svn.so
Architectures in the fat file: subversion/mod_dav_svn/.libs/mod_dav_svn.so are: ppc7400 ppc64 i386 x86_64
```

I keep a copy of the environment in my home directory. Whenever I build something, I copy `env-sh`, edit it as needed, source it, then build away. There is a lot more information hidden in the depths of `developer.apple.com` like [Tech Note 2137](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2005/tn2137.html) and the [Universal Binary Programming Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/universal_binary/universal_binary_intro/universal_binary_intro.html) as well.

Good luck. I know that I am still navigating my way through this morass of fun.

Comment: I tried running your steps above, but the resulting mod_dav_svn.so is still i386 when I do lipo. I have the latest SDK installed(the one that comes with the iPhone 3.0 kit).

Everything you say makes a lot of sense. Just not getting it to build as anything but i386.

Comment: I did run into problems with some packages that were not using CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in the proper places but subversion gets that one right. Make sure that you do a `make distclean' at the top-level before you run the configure script. I tried this with a clean fetch of svn-1.6.2 and it worked on my MacBook Pro. You are looking at the built one and not the installed one right?

Comment: This was super helpful, thanks.  As a side note, I had to do the envvars / DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH trick mentioned here afterwards: http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/19

Answer (score 1):

The answer of D.Shawley didn't work for me (I get an error during make) but maybe I didn't do it right.
But... since I don't use svn in my http-server I managed to "solve" the problem by commenting all SVN modules in httpd.conf. In my case:

file: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

#LoadModule dav_svn_module     libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so

#LoadModule authz_svn_module   libexec/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so

And after commenting those lines, I was able to start apache again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was compiled for the wrong architecture. Mayhaps 64-bit?