# gmon.out isn't created when I compile with -pg flag with g++

Tags: c++, macos, g++, gprof

I'm running on Mac OSX, version 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion). I have the following simple C++ code.

**`main.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!"<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Goodbye world!"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get gprof to work on my computer.  As the [manual](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC2) suggests, I enter the following two lines into my terminal:

```
g++ -g -pg main.cpp -o a.out 
./a.out
```

However this does not generate a `gmon.out` file as it is supposed to.  When I try typing `gprof` in the terminal, it says:

```
gprof: can't open: gmon.out (No such file or directory)
```

which is to be expected since `gmon.out` isn't there...

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:  Some other things that may help:

- My friend, who has a similar OS X version (I can ask him later to confirm), and the exact same versions of `g++` and `gprof`, was able to
  use `gprof` successfully as I have outlined.
- I'm using an older version of `g++` but I have read online that updating to a newer version didn't help.
- `a.out` works perfectly, it prints out `Hello world!` and `Goodbye world!`. I also tried this with a more complex C++ program with
  several classes and it still has the same problem.  Everything
  compiles and runs normally but no gmon.out file is produced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101545/problem-with-gprof-on-os-x-program-is-not-of-the-host-architecture, although one of the answers claims that `gprof` now works on OS X 10.6. I can't see that you're doing anything wrong, exactly what you're doing works as you'd expect on my Linux system.

Comment: Yeah, I have 10.8.5, I saw that question too but I figured I'd start a new thread because I have a newer version of OS X and that thread didn't seem to get anywhere.  There is also a "test is not of the host architecture" issue that the other person encounters which I don't.

Comment: Despite what people are saying, `-pg` doesn't work on any of my systems 10.7-10.9.4. I do believe you can install your own version of gcc (separate from the Apple-provided version) and profiling will work there.

Comment: Even if *gprof* does work here, you will get no samples in your code, because, outside of I/O which *gprof* does not see anyway, the code you have compiled takes about a nanosecond. It could run thousands of times over in the time between *gprof* samples.

Comment: `-pg` and gprof definitely don't work for me in OSX 10.10.3.  Even tried running `cc` rather than `clang` and explicitly calling `exit`.

Comment: @NickDesaulniers on my Mac, `/usr/bin/cc` is symlinked to `/usr/bin/clang`

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize that OS X/MacOS does not provide GNU GCC on the system by default.

Note the output of this command:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/clang++
```

These executables look identical. (Actually! It looks like they are different, but somehow the filesize is identical!)

As far as I can tell, clang doesn't support the production of gprof output. As confusing as it may be, the `gcc` program will run clang.

I would recommend trying to use homebrew to install GCC on OS X/MacOS. You do want to be careful about how it gets installed, etc., so that you know which command corresponds to which compiler.